# Show “Suppress Warning” Context Menu Item in Visual Studio 2017 for warnings where the option appears to be missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, suppress-warnings

When working with unity code warning `CS0649` and `CS0414` fire when unity rebuilds the solution, even when the unity attribute `[SerializeField]` is applied.  I want to suppress these false positives in source through the context menu in the Error list, or the quick actions menu.  I do not want to globally disable `CS0649` and/or `CS0414` because in a case where `[SerializeField]` was forgotten or is not appropriate the warning is obviously helpful.

I've edited the `csc.rsp` file and added `/w40649` to re-enable the warning in visual studio, however when I right click the error the "suppress error in source" option is missing.  I can manually suppress the error with `#pragma warning disable CS0649, CS0414` and re-enabling with `#pragma warning restore CS0649, CS0414` However this is very tedious to modify by hand.

I've already tried ["Suppress Warning" menuitem in Visual Studio 2010 is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617107/suppress-warning-menuitem-in-visual-studio-2010-is-not-available) however this did not seem to add back the context menu item, although it does appear to be listed in the tools customization in Context menu > "Other Context Menus | Error List" as expected, oddly.

Without suppression:

```cs
    [SerializeField]
    private bool flashCustomColor = false;

    [SerializeField, OneLine.OneLine, ShowIf("flashCustomColor")]
    private FlashingColors flashingColors;

    [System.Serializable]
    private struct FlashingColors
    {
        public Color GetHurtColor() => hurtColor ?? Color.red;

        [SerializeField]
        private Color? hurtColor;

        public Color GetNormalColor() => normalColor ?? Color.white;

        [SerializeField]
        private Color? normalColor;
    }
```

With Suppression:

```cs
    [SerializeField]
#pragma warning restore IDE0044, CS0414
    private bool flashCustomColor = false;
#pragma warning restore IDE0044, CS0414

    [SerializeField, OneLine.OneLine, ShowIf("flashCustomColor")]
    private FlashingColors flashingColors;

    [System.Serializable]
    private struct FlashingColors
    {
        public Color GetHurtColor() => hurtColor ?? Color.red;

        [SerializeField]
#pragma warning disable CS0649, IDE0044
        private Color? hurtColor;
#pragma warning restore CS0649, IDE0044

        public Color GetNormalColor() => normalColor ?? Color.white;

        [SerializeField]
#pragma warning disable CS0649, IDE0044
        private Color? normalColor;
#pragma warning restore CS0649, IDE0044
    }
```

I am trying to enable that context menu item, but it doesn't seem to be immediately available for warning CS0649.  This is what currently shows up:
[image]
But on other errors I can suppress it as like below: 
[image]
**EDIT: I'm aware that I can set the field to `= null;` in classes, but structs can't take default initializers.  I've updated the images to reflect this.**

Comment: the simpler answer is, set values.  Even if its =null, for gameobjects, this prevents the issue as you are asking to only suspress when its for a serialized field, not for anything else.  In short the compiler cant see you set values in the inspector so complains.  Setting a default value to the default value it would have had clears the message

Comment: @BugFinder This is great for classes, but you can't do this on structs.  Thanks for pointing this out though, I've edited my question.

Comment: I've had this same problem, but it only affected about a dozen files, so i just enclosed them fully in #pragma warning disable / restore. You might want to rearrange your code so that you only have a handful of files that need to have these warnings disabled that way.

Comment: Interesting you mentioned structs, but your example doesnt show then the actual problem of the structs you are trying to show in the inspector

Comment: @BugFinder I didn't originally include the struct case because I didn't think it was directly relevant to context menu and I wanted to use a small and easy to reproduce example.  The struct case requires more boiler plate and context to make sense.  I have added it to the question for clarity though.  The last example should now reflect the edge case with structs.

Comment: @WhiteMaple A lot of it is legacy code from past projects and code from asset packages.  It's a lot to refactor, and I don't want to risk screwing something up in a purely cosmetic refactor if I can simply suppress the benign warnings.

Comment: Having the same problem here, found any solution yet ?